# multiple models for each partial c# dotnet core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

```
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contactinfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contactinfo-tab"><partial name="_ChildInfo"></partial></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="registerNewChild" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="registerNewChild-tab"><partial name="_ChildReg"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="yourkids" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="yourkids-tab"><partial name="_YourKidsTab"></partial></div>
</div>
```

I have 3 tabs on my dashboard. I can't seem to find a way to have have 3 different models assigned to each partial since they are all called from the same route.

EDIT: Additional code upon request.

```
///////////////////////cshtml
@{
if(Model != null)
{
    foreach(Participant i in Model)
        {
            <p>@i.ParticipantFirstName</p>
        }
}
if(Model == null)
{
    <p>null?</p>
}
```

}
test123

```
//viewModel
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LeagueProject.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        private Context db;
        public ViewModel(Context context)
        {
            db = context;
        }
        public Participant participant { get; set; }
        public List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
        // List<Participant> allParticipants = db.Participants.Include(i=>i.Parent).ToList();

    public class Participant
    {
        [Key]
        public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "must be at least 2 characters")]
        public string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "must be at least 2 characters")]
        public string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        public string ParticipantGender { get; set; }

        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        // [Range(8, 20, ErrorMessage="this league if roages 8-19")]
        // public int ParticipantAge { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Need a date of birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public System.DateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User Parent { get; set; }

        public List<MMLeagueParticipant> allLeagues { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: i looked through the docs but couldn't find anything on models for each partial.

Answer (score 2):

For using three models in the same page, you could put these models to a view model like below:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Test1 Test1 { get; set; }
    public Test2 Test2 { get; set; }
    public List<Test3> Test3 { get; set; }
}
public class Test1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Test2
{
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
public class Test3
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
}
```

View(Index.cshtml):

```
@model MyViewModel
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="contactinfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contactinfo-tab">
        <partial name="_ChildInfo" model="@Model.Test1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="registerNewChild" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="registerNewChild-tab">
        <partial name="_ChildReg" model="@Model.Test2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="yourkids" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="yourkids-tab">
        <partial name="_YourKidsTab" model="@Model.Test3"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Partial views:

1. _ChildInfo.cshtml

   ```
   @model Test1
   <h1>_ChildInfo</h1>
   @Model.Name
   ```
2. _ChildReg.cshtml

   ```
   @model Test2
   <h1>_ChildReg</h1>
   @Model.Age
   ```
3. _YourKidsTab.cshtml

   ```
   @model List<Test3>
   <h1>_YourKidsTab</h1>

   @foreach(var item in Model)
   { 
       @item.Class 
   }
   ```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel()
    {
        Test1 = new Test1() { Name = "aa" },
        Test2 = new Test2() { Age = "23" },
        Test3 = new List<Test3>(){new Test3() { Class = "Class2" }}
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

**Update:**

**Dashboard.cshtml**:

```
 @model ViewModel

 <partial name="_YourKidsTab" model="@Model.allParticipants "/>
```

**_YourKidsTab.cshtml:**

```
@model List<Participant>
//....
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("dashboard")]
public IActionResult Dashboard()
{
    if(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
    ViewBag.loggedinUser = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("DashboardTab", 0);
    List<Participant> allParticipants = db.Participants.Include(i=>i.Parent).ToList();

    //add this ......
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel()
    {
       allParticipants  = allParticipants 
    };

    return View("Dashboard", model);   //change here..
}
```

Comment: what if one of the models im trying to pass into my partial is a list `List<Participant> allParticipants = db.Participants.Include(i=>i.Parent).ToList();` i know i would use @model List<Participant> in my partial; but how would i do that in my ViewModel

Comment: Just add `public List<Participant> Participant{ get; set; }` to the view model is ok.  Then use  `<partial name="xxx" model="@Model.Participant"/>` in main view.

Comment: i tried that and a few other things but im getting an error now. InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LeagueProject.Models.Participant]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel'.

Comment: Please share your detailed code. The error message means you pass List<Participant> model but your razor view use `@model ViewModel`. You could change  `@model ViewModel` to `@model  List<Participant>`. Or change the pass data.

Comment: my guess is it doesn't like that in my dashboardcontroller im passing in List<Participant>. not sure how to work around this since i cant do ViewModel.List<Participant>

Comment: Hi @Jgrewall,  please check my updated answer.